# Non volatile multi-threaded write which is thread visible

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a variable that I need to set the value of that I want thread visible. I have no idea what thread is doing the reading a writing.

The variable is only ever set once so by setting it as `volatile` I prevent the variable value from being read from the CPU cache (or so is my understanding). Write once, read many.

I am unable to get this variable into a constructor to use final.

My rough flow is:

```
thread 1: set value x
thread 1: fire notification to say x is ready.
thread 2: read x.
```

My understanding is that I can do the following:

```
public void setX(int value) {
    Object o = new Object();
    synchronized(o) {
        this.x = value;
    }
}
```

And because of the happens-before principle, the value will be written out to memory. Is that correct?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve again?  maybe you just need a singleton

Comment: `synchronized(o)` doesn't _happen before_ anything in your example because `o` refers to a different object each time `setX()` is called.  Synchronization only means anything when two or more threads synchronize on the _same_ object.

Comment: @Cheetah I understand that thread 2 must wait until `x` is set in thread 1, however I would like to know if thread 1 should also wait until thread 2 wants to read `x`...

Answer (score 1):

Don't set it to `volatile`. As a thumb rule, use `volatile` if the value of that variable is changing and multiple threads read / write to that variable.In your case  *you want the reads to be cached. because the value of x won't change*. Using volatile will *reduce performance* In your case, you will just have to ensure that the `set()` happens before the `get()` . Which will actually happen because unless `someThread` notifies the other thread, the other thread will not read the value of x.

PS : I am assuming that the other thread(s) will not read value of `x` unless notified. Let me know if I got your question wrong.

Comment: Surely the value could still be sitting in a cache.

Comment: @Cheetah -  Will your threads be reading this value *without being notified*?

Comment: No, but sure if its not volatile and thread 1 sets the value of x, that value may not have been written into memory by the time thread 2 gets the notification it can read....

Comment: @Cheetah  - *Synchronization* also ensures a *happens before* . You could use it instead of *volatile*. bTW removed this point from my answer

Comment: so my example in the OP is correct to achieve what I wish...?

Comment: @Cheetah - More or less yes. Except perhaps you would want to look into what object to lock on..

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing on the object created in the method is pointless.
How you `notify()` all reading threads is a question you will need to answer yourself - do you intend to have them `wait()`ing for this notification?
I would suggest to return `null` or `throw` from the getter if the value is not set yet instead...

Comment: he does not try to notify.... he only wants to ensure that `x` is sure to be synchronized to "main" memory. however I agree that just create object to do so is not neccesary, we can use `this` as well.